# Is there a way I could take only desired indexed range of elements from each row and column in a matrix?

Tags: python

Let us say that I have a matrix of 10x10 elements. What I want is to take elements from 0 to 7th column from each row till the 6th row only and discard all others. For example:

```
[08, 02, 22, 97, 38, 15, 00, 40, 00, 75, 
49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 
81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 
52, 70, 95, 23, 04, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 
22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 
24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 03, 45, 02, 44, 75, 
32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 
67, 26, 20, 68, 02, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 
24, 55, 58, 05, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 
21, 36, 23, 09, 75, 00, 76, 44, 20, 45, 
78, 17, 53, 28, 22 75, 31, 67, 15, 94]
```

I only need elements from **0 to 7th column** and from **each row till the 6th row**. You can see the image. [This selected portion of the matrix is what I need.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWUzq.png)

Comment: how is this so called "matrix" actually stored? Is it actually a normal 1 dimensional list of ints like it seems to be here?

Comment: That is not a valid Python list (you have `ints` starting with 0). Also, you have 110 elements.

Comment: can you use numpy?

Answer (score 1):

Since your matrix is stored in a 1-dimensional list, I assume that you have an arbitrary variable (`actual_cols`) that will determine the number of columns a row can have. I also assume that you want the extracted matrix will be stored in a 1-dimensional list similar to the original matrix. If those are the cases then you can try this approach:

```
a = [8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 00, 40, 0, 75, 
49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 
81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 
52, 70, 95, 23, 4, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 
22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 
24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3, 45, 2, 44, 75, 
32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 
67, 26, 20, 68, 2, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 
24, 55, 58, 5, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 
21, 36, 23, 9, 75, 0, 76, 44, 20, 45, 
78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94]

actual_cols = 10
col = 7
row = 6

b = [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if (i % actual_cols < col) and (i / actual_cols) < row]
print(b)
```

You can also do something similar if you want to store the extracted matrix in a 2-dimensional list

```
a = [8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 00, 40, 0, 75, 
49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 
81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 
52, 70, 95, 23, 4, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 
22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 
24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3, 45, 2, 44, 75, 
32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 
67, 26, 20, 68, 2, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 
24, 55, 58, 5, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 
21, 36, 23, 9, 75, 0, 76, 44, 20, 45, 
78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94]

actual_cols = 10
col = 7
row = 6

b = [[a[i*actual_cols + j] for j in range(col)] for i in range(int(len(a)/actual_cols)) if i < row]
print(b)
```

If you store the original matrix in a 2-dimensional list then it will easier to extract them

```
a = [[8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 00, 40, 0, 75],
[49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87], 
[81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71], 
[52, 70, 95, 23, 4, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24], 
[22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92], 
[24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3, 45, 2, 44, 75], 
[32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38], 
[67, 26, 20, 68, 2, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63], 
[24, 55, 58, 5, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17], 
[21, 36, 23, 9, 75, 0, 76, 44, 20, 45], 
[78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94]]

col = 7
row = 6

b = [x[:col] for x in a[:row]]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

My method is to turn the matrix into a 1D array and pick the numbers based on their position. ALSO, this method can keep your numbers format such as "02" because I basically use string and list methods.

Now I assumed that you have turned your matrix into a 1D array. Since your require numbers that fall into the 0-7 columns and 0-6 rows, you basically only want 8/10 columns and 6/11 rows. Which means you'd only want to iterate the first 6*10 = 60 numbers (10 is the len of one line) and our target goal is the positions of 0-7,10-17,20-27...

Check the code below 3.

```
new_l = [] # this is to store all qualified numbers (falling in the requested columns and requested rows)
position_list = list(range(6*10)) # you only want to iterate the first 6 rows, so 60 numbers in total
for i in range(0,60,10):
    line_position_list =position_list[i:i+8] # slice the list into 6 smaller pieces and extract only the first 8 elements.
    for position in line_position_list:
        new_l.append(l[position]) # append these numbers into the new list
print(new_l)

# if you want to keep the shape of array, turn everything to string and then add \n at the end of the 7th element
for i in range(0,len(new_l),8):
    new_l[i] = "\n" + new_l[i]
print(new_l)
new_string = ",".join(new_l)
print(new_string)

Output

08, 02, 22, 97, 38, 15, 00, 40,
 49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57,
 81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29,
 52, 70, 95, 23, 04, 60, 11, 42,
 22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89,
 24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 03, 45, 02
```

UPDATE:
l is the 1D array of all string typed elements:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1txH.png)

Comment: What does  **l[position]** in 
```new_l.append(l[position]) ```  has to do? You have not defined the variable __l__

Comment: @RabinBK sorry my bad, l is the 1D array of your string types elements. I’ve updated it in the answer, see the image. The reason I use string is to keep some of your number format: 02 for example.

Comment: To get l from your original matrix, you probably need to do some string split and replace and join method. Let me know if you need the specific code. Also, the function of new_l.append(l[position]) is to adds numbers that belong to column 0-7 and row 0-6 to a new list new_l. The position comes from the line_position_list, which stores all positions that fall into your requests. (line_position_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13..., 20, 21, 22, ..., 27,...,  30, ... , 40, ..., 50, 51, 52, ...,57])